# Paypal Express Module Doesn't Store Correct Country in magento 1.7

Tags: paypal, magento-1.7

Don't know if anyone else has seen this one, but we've had some orders come through where a customer has their paypal default shipping address set to another country (India for example), and when they try to check out with Paypal Express it will take them to the order review page that lets them choose their shipping address. If they change this to be the UK (where we're based) the order will apparently go through fine, but in Magento it'll store the shipping for the country as being the default country for the Paypal account.

All the other fields seem to update fine, and if the billing address is tied to the shipping address then it seems to work fine too, but it's causing issues with the shipping label generation because it's creating shipping labels which say they're to be an international order. Site's running 1.7.0.2, any help you could give would be really appreciated